# Removing "Website" Field from the contact info

Tags: profiles, contact

I want to remove the website field from the user contact info. I use the following to remove the AIM,Jabber and Yahoo IM . But I am not able to use this to remove the website. Someone please help.

```
function remove_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
    unset($contactmethods['aim']);
    unset($contactmethods['yim']);
    unset($contactmethods['jabber']);
    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','remove_contactmethods',10,1);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Revisited and updated answer:*

We can't use the `user_contactmethods` filter to remove the website wrapper, because this piece is hardcoded in the `user-edit.php` file and not part of the filterable  *user contacts* loop, generated by:

```
wp_get_user_contact_methods( $profileuser )
```

### Hiding it with CSS

The *website* row element now got it's own `.user-url-wrap` class:

```
<tr class="user-url-wrap">
    <th><label for="url"><?php _e('Website') ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="url" name="url" id="url" 
               value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->user_url ) ?>" 
               class="regular-text code" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Previously we had to use jQuery, to target the parent row of the `#url` field, for removal.

But now we can easily target the *website* wrapper and hide it with CSS:

```
function remove_website_row_wpse_94963_css()
{
    echo '<style>tr.user-url-wrap{ display: none; }</style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'remove_website_row_wpse_94963_css' );
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php',   'remove_website_row_wpse_94963_css' );
```

### Hiding other fields

There are similar row classes:

```
tr.user-{field}-wrap
```

available for the fields:

```
admin-color,
comment-shortcuts,
admin-bar-front,
user-login,
role,
super-admin,
first-name, 
last-name, 
nickname, 
display-name, 
email,
description, 
pass1, 
pass2, 
sessions, 
capabilities,
...
```

including all the fields from the dynamic *user contacts* methods.

Here we just replace the `{field}` part with the corresponding field name.

### Screenshots

**Before removing the website row:**
[image: Before]

---

**After removing the website row:**
[image: After]

Comment: You should use `.remove()` instead of `.hide()`

Comment: This is not working for me. This code should be put in finctions.php right??

Comment: You have to be a non-admin when you test it or comment out the `if` sentence with the capability test. It works in `functions.php`, but I think it's better to have it in a plugin so you don't loose it when you change the theme.

Comment: How about this `apply_filters( "user_{$name}_label", $desc );`

Comment: This only modifies the labels, for the dynamically created *contact methods*, but not the corresponding input text fields. The *website* field is also not part of these dynamic  *contact methods*. It would be handy though, to have such filters for the whole `user-*-wrap` parts ;-)  @BradDalton

Comment: Thought so. Good opportunity to submit an enhancement.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved the problem with ob_ functions and DOMDocument. It's better than jQuery or CSS for protecting the form.

I use this kind of solution every time when I can't access a part of HTML content through a hook.

```
function remove_extra_field_profile()
{

    $current_file_url =  preg_replace( "#\?.*#" , "" , basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );

    if( $current_file_url == "profile.php" )
    {
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', function(){ ob_start("profile_callback"); } );
        add_action( 'shutdown', function(){ ob_end_flush(); } );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_extra_field_profile' );


function profile_callback( $html )
{
    $profile_dom = new DOMDocument;
    $profile_dom->loadHTML( $html );

    $all_lines = $profile_dom->getElementsByTagname( 'tr' );

    $excludes = array(
        'user-rich-editing-wrap',
        'user-admin-color-wrap',
        'user-comment-shortcuts-wrap',
        'show-admin-bar user-admin-bar-front-wrap',
        'user-url-wrap',
        'user-description-wrap'
        );

    $deletes = array();

    foreach ( $all_lines as $line ) 
    {
        $tr_calss = $line->getAttribute("class");

        if( in_array( $tr_calss, $excludes ) )
        {
            $deletes[] = $line;
        }
    }

    $deletes[] = $profile_dom->getElementsByTagname( 'h2' )->item(0);

    foreach ($deletes as $delete) 
    {
        $delete->parentNode->removeChild( $delete );
    }

    return $profile_dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is great.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @birgire's and justifying @Patricia Walton's answer, if you only add

`add_action('admin_head-user-edit.php','remove_website_row_wpse_94963');`

it will only be gone from the page where admin is editing a profile. To also make it disappear when a user edits its own profile add also

`add_action('admin_head-profile.php','remove_website_row_wpse_94963');`, like this:

```
function remove_website_row_wpse_94963() {
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
        // hide only for non-admins
        echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('#url').parents('tr').remove();});</script>";
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-user-edit.php','remove_website_row_wpse_94963');
add_action('admin_head-profile.php','remove_website_row_wpse_94963');
```

Comment: You are missing one third add_action for the new user page:
`add_action('admin_head-user-new.php','remove_website_row_wpse_94963');`

Answer (score 1):

The code was not working for me either, but changing the add_action to point to profile.php did work.

```
function remove_website_row_wpse_94963() {
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
        // hide only for non-admins
        echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function()    
            {jQuery('#url').parents('tr').remove();});</script>";
    }
}

add_action('admin_head-user-edit.php','remove_website_row_wpse_94963');
```

Comment: I can't see in what the code you posted differe form @birgire one.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @birgire's answer, I wrote this into an array so it's a little easier to read:

```
function awb_remove_user_profile_fields_with_css() {
//Hide unwanted fields in the user profile
$fieldsToHide = [
    'rich-editing',
    'admin-color',
    'comment-shortcuts',
    'admin-bar-front',
    'user-login',
    'role',
    'super-admin',
    //'first-name', 
    //'last-name', 
    'nickname', 
    'display-name', 
    //'email',
    'description', 
    //'pass1', 
    //'pass2', 
    'sessions', 
    'capabilities',
    'syntax-highlighting',
    'url'

    ];

    //add the CSS
    foreach ($fieldsToHide as $fieldToHide) {
        echo '<style>tr.user-'.$fieldToHide.'-wrap{ display: none; }</style>';
    }

    //fields that don't follow the wrapper naming convention
    echo '<style>tr.user-profile-picture{ display: none; }</style>';

    //all subheadings
    echo '<style>#your-profile h2{ display: none; }</style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'awb_remove_user_profile_fields_with_css' );
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php',   'awb_remove_user_profile_fields_with_css' );
```